# Compute the product of digits of P

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, integers, power-towers

> Give $P$ a integer number where
>   $$P=2^{3^{4^{5^{\dots1000}}}}$$
>   Then
>
> 1. Compute The product of dígits of $P$
> 2. Compute $P\pmod{5}$

for The segond i think its will be something like
$$\begin{align}
2&\equiv2\pmod5\\
2^2&\equiv4\pmod5\\
2^3&\equiv3\pmod5\\
2^4&\equiv1\pmod5\\
3&\equiv3\pmod4\\
3^2&\equiv1\pmod4\\
P&=2^{3^{4^{5^{\dots1000}}}}\\
&\equiv2^{3^{2}}\pmod5\\
&\equiv2^{1}\pmod5\\
&\equiv2\pmod5
\end{align}$$
but for The first question i dont know how to start.

Comment: Are there supposed to be a couple of $\mod 4$ congruencies in the middle there?

Comment: It's likely to be very hard to prove (though you can possibly use a version of your calculation to compute $P\bmod 10^i$ for large enough values of $i$ to be certain), but the odds are almost overwhelming that the product of the digits of $P$ is zero...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1\le a\le 1000$, let
$$ f(a):=a^{(a+1)^{(a+2)^{\cdots^{1000}}}}.$$
Since $f(4)$ is even, $f(3)$ is a power of $9$. Then since $2^9\equiv 2\pmod5$, we conclude $f(2)=2^{9\cdot9\cdot9\cdot\ldots\cdot9}\equiv 2\pmod 5$, thus answering the second part.

For even $a<1000$ we clearly have $f(a)\equiv 0\pmod 4$, whereas for odd $a$ we have $f(a)\equiv 1\pmod 8$ as it is the square of an odd number.

We shall work our way down from $f(4)$.
From $4^5\equiv -1\pmod{5^2}$ (and of course $(-1)^5\equiv -1\pmod {5^2}$)
we conclude $f(4)=4^{{5\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot 5}}\equiv -1\pmod{5^2}$ (in fact, $f(4)\equiv -1$ modulo *really* high powers of $5$).
Together with $f(4)\equiv 0\pmod 4$, this implies that $f(4)\equiv 24\pmod{{2^25^2}}$. As $2^25^2=\phi(5^3)$, this implies 
$f(3)\equiv 3^{24}\pmod{5^3}$. This can be computed (e.g., by repeated squaring) as $f(3)\equiv 106\pmod{5^3}$. Together with $f(3)\equiv 1\pmod 4$, we conclude $f(3)\equiv 481\pmod{2^25^3}$.
Therefore $f(2)\equiv 2^{481}\pmod{5^4}$. Again by repeated squaring we compute $f(2)\equiv 352\pmod{5^4}$. Together with $f(2)\equiv 0\pmod{2^4}$ we conclude $f(2)\equiv 352\pmod{10^4}$. Therefore the decimal digit expansion of $f(2)$ ends in $\ldots 0352$, and the product of all decimal digits of $f(2)$ is zero.

*Remark:* Already $2^{3^{4^5}}$ ends in $\ldots 5280666917347210\mathbf{0352}$, but $2^{3^4}$ ends in $\ldots\mathbf 2352$.

Comment: Now that's an answer.